# Sort an array based on the other array

Tags: sorting, dart, filter

I am trying to sort a list with reference to another list. Consider this example,

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var array2 = [4,6,3];
```

Now, I want the result to be like this,

```
result = [4,6,3,1,2,5];
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
 var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 var array2 = [4,6,3];
 
 var result = [...array2.where((i) => array1.contains(i)), ...array1.where((i) => !array2.contains(i))];

print('resulting array: ${result}');
```

The first part collects everything in array2 that lives in the first array, the second part collect everything not in the second array aka the missing values

Comment: Ohhh I see, Thank you so much

Comment: @Albert If it's helpful don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var array2 = [4,8,3];
    var sayac=1;
    for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
            if(array1.indexOf(array2[i])==-1){
            array1[array1.length+sayac]=array2[i];
                sayac++;
              }
    }
        console.log(array1);
    
    
    </script>
```